# my google snippet is not showing the data from the correct url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-plus, google-plus-one

This may be a little confusing, so I added an example,
http://searchengineland.com/bing-rises-above-17-search-market-share-as-google-slips-comscore-159746
When clicking the +1 button here, inside the snippet it shows the text and URL from that page.

However, my snippet shows text from the homepage URL, not from the URL I gave it. Why is this and how can I fix it? Sorry if I'm unclear. the code I'm using is below.

```
<g:plusone size="medium" count="true" href="http://aaaaaa.com/social/comments/'.$row["id"].'">
</g:plusone>
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet is generated using the Schema.org markup on your page.  To update the text, simply update the `itemprop="description"` value in your markup for each page within your site. This markup generally looks like:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

For more information on the snippet, as well as alternatives to Schema markup, see https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/.